# solr query not returning results

Tags: solr

When I enter search url

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?qt=standard&rows=10&q=*:*
```

I get a response with 10 documents.

But when I want to test specific query, then nothing comes up. For example:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select?qt=standard&rows=10&q=white
```

Why is that happening? I clearly see in results, that there is document with word "White" in it. So Why solr dont return that document as result.?

Comment: Please vote up if you find this question useful. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`q=*:*` searches for all content on all the documents, hence you get back the results.

`q=white` will search for white on the default search field, which is usually text if you have not modified the schema.xml.

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

You can change the default field to be the field you want to search on.
OR use specific field to search on the specific field e.g. title `q=title:white`

If you want to search on multiple field, you can combine the fields into one field by using copyfields or use dismax request handler.

Comment: I know it's been a while, but it looks like this has been deprecated in 4.0.